# Evaluate $a$ and $b$ s.t. the piecewise function is differentiable at two points

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Evaluate $a$ and $b$ s.t. the piecewise function is differentiable at $x=1$ and $x=2$ at the same time.

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            ax^2+bx+1 & \quad x ≥ 1 \\
            -1 & \quad x < 1
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

So first, we gotta prove it's continuous at these points.

$$f(1)=a+b+1$$

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} -1=-1$$

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} ax^2+bx+1=a+b+1$$

$-1=a+b+1 ⟹ a+b=-2$

How do I continue this for $x=2$? And then for differentbility? Im kinda new to this and need a little help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be differentiable at $x = 1$, then the following limit needs to exits:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h}.$$  For this to exist you need to consider both the left and right limits:
$$\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{-1 - (a+b+1)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{-(a+b+2)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{0}{h} = 0$$ using the fact that $a + b = -2$.  Now for the right:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{a(1+h)^2 + b(1+h) + 1 - (a+b+1)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{a + 2ah + ah^2+b+bh+1-a-b-1}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{2ah + ah^2 + bh}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}2a+ah+b\\
&=2a+b.
\end{align*}

Now, for the limit to exist, you must have $2a+b = 0$, which gives you two equations in two unknowns to solve for $a$ and $b$, and I trust you can take it from here.

Comment: yeah, okay I can solve the system of equations, but I want it to be differentiable even for $x=2$. For the right and left side limit of $x=2$ which equation do I use, because usually when you're given $x=a$, the conditions also contain that number $a$, but in this case we have $x=2$ and the conditions don't contain 2. Srry if im not being too clear.

Comment: Because I think i might end up with a system of 4 equations, so 2 for continuity and 2 for differentiability. But I don't know which equations to use for the right and left hand side limit for $x=2$

Comment: Once you solve these two equations you will have $a$ and $b$. After that you just need to verify that the resulting function is differentiable at $x=2$.